# Find the general solution of the problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of the problem $$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xx}(x, t)=0, 0<x<\pi, t>0 \tag {*} \\ u(0, t)=0, t>0 \\ u_x(\pi ,t)=-u_{tt}(\pi ,t), t>0$$

I have done the following:

We are looking for solutions of the form $$u(x, t)=X(x) \cdot T(t)$$

$$u(0, t)=X(0) \cdot T(t)=0 \Rightarrow X(0)=0 \\ X'(\pi ) \cdot T(t)+X(\pi ) \cdot T''(t)=0 \Rightarrow X'(\pi)+X(\pi )\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=0$$

$$(*) \Rightarrow X(x) \cdot T''(t)-X''(x) \cdot T(t)=0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{X(x) \cdot T''(t)}{X(x) \cdot T(t)}-\frac{X''(x) \cdot T(t)}{X(x) \cdot T(t)}=0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda$$

So, we get the following two problems: 
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0, 0<x<\pi \\ 
X(0)=0 \\
X'(\pi )-\lambda X(\pi )=0
\end{matrix}\right\}(1)
$$

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
T''(t)+\lambda T(t)=0, t>0
\end{matrix}\right\}(2)$$

For the problem $(1)$ we do the following:

The characteristic polynomial is $d^2+\lambda=0$.

- $\lambda <0$ :

  $X(x)=c_1 \sinh (\sqrt{-\lambda} x)+c_2 \cosh (\sqrt{-\lambda}x)$

  Using the initial values we get that $X(x)=0$, trivial solution.
- $\lambda=0$ :

  $X(x)=c_1 x+c_2$

  Using the initial values we get that $X(x)=0$, trivial solution.
- $\lambda >0$ :

  $X(x)=c_1 cos (\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

  $X(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1=0 \Rightarrow X(x)=c_2 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

  $X'(\pi )-\lambda X(\pi )=0 \Rightarrow \tan (\sqrt{\lambda} \pi )=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$

That means that the eigenvalue problem $(1)$ has only positive eigenvalues $0<\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \dots < \lambda_k < \dots $ .

---

The graph of $\tan (y \cdot \pi)$ and $\frac{1}{y}$ is the following: [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Btan%28y*%28pi%29%29%2C1%2Fy%2C%20%7By%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%22]https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Btan%28y*%28pi%29%29%2C1%2Fy%2C%20%7By%2C0%2C20%7D%5D)

The $\tan (y \cdot \pi )$ has a period of $1$ and in each period it has exactly 1 intersection with $\frac 1 y$.
Since there are a countable number of periods of the tangent, that means that the number of solutions is also countable.

The eigenfunctions are $\sin (\sqrt{\lambda_k} x)$.

For the problem $(2)$ we have the following:

$$T''(t)+\lambda T(t)=0 \Rightarrow T_k(t)=C_1 \sin (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)+C_2 \cos (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)$$

The eigenfunctions are $\sin (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)$, $\cos (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)$.

So, the general solution is the following:

$$u(x, t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k \cos (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)+b_k \sin (\sqrt{\lambda_k} t)) \sin (\sqrt{\lambda_k} x)$$

Is this correct??

Comment: To check if it is correct, just differentiate your $u(x,t)$ and see if it satisfies your IC and BCs. Note, your $u$ doesn't satisfy $u(0,t) = 0$.

Comment: Oh you`re right... I edited my initial post... Is it correct now?? @Mattos

Comment: Does $u$ satisfy the last condition $u_x(\pi,t)=-u_{tt}(\pi,t)$ ?? @Mattos

Comment: How can this condition be satisfied?? At the one side of the equation we will have cos and at the other side we will have sin, or not?? @Mattos

Comment: This does not seem right to me, for the problem to be well posed, surely you should have two initial conditions as well; i.e., $u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will need initial conditions to find the full solution, but regardless, I think your solution is correct, since $\lambda_k$ is chosen such that $X'_k(\pi)=\lambda_kX_k(\pi)$, and we have set

$u(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty T_kX_k$ so $$u_{tt}(\pi,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty T_k''X_k(\pi)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty-\lambda_kT_k(t)X_k(\pi),$$
and
$$u_x(\pi,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty T_kX_k'(\pi)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_kT_kX_k(\pi).$$
So the equality you seek holds. I think the confusion came in because you did not state the actual values of $\lambda_k$.